# Misleading text/percentage for Electorate badge progress

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, electorate-badge

On the right side of SO, I see a "Badge Progress" control.

Amongst other things, it says:

> Electorate 
>      682 question votes (113% done). 
>      <sub>Your voting ratio is 0.13 - you need to vote on more questions</sub>

The last sentence is in small, light gray text -- it's easy to miss.

The "113% done" is a little misleading -- it makes it seem like you should have the badge already.

I would suggest that when the vote count exceeds the minimum (100%) it should change to:

> Electorate 
>      <sub>682 question votes (OK!).</sub> 
>      Your voting ratio is **0.13** - you need to vote on more questions

Screenshot:
[image: enter link description here]

It should be somewhat like: [image]

Comment: Perhaps the percentage should cap at 99% if the voting ratio is not high enough?

Comment: That's kind of wrong though, if you don't notice the secondary requirement you'll be voting on more questions without the percentage increasing and you'll show up here and complain.

Comment: @animuson I disagree. If you have met the number of votes requirement, it should say so. If it stays at 99%, everyone will have the impression that the vote counter is bugged, and you'll see complaints here.

Comment: If the ratio is under .25 it should base the percent off the number of votes required to get to .25.

Comment: Where do you see this? Can you post a screenshot or respond in comment? I don't have this on SO.

Comment: @Yuck: Added screenshot. In review section, after getting Strunk and White

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it so we display the correct percentage done in all cases ...

Now maths is not my strongest point, but I think this formula works:

```
var left = (0.25 * (stats.AllTimeQuestions + stats.AllTimeAnswers + 0.0) 
  - stats.AllTimeQuestions) / 0.75;
```

So, if you happen to only vote on answers you will not be 100% at 600, instead it will track till the amount you have left.

Comment: This is much improved, but the font sizes still seem backwards in this case -- the stuff you still need to do should be bigger than the part you've already done.

Comment: @CraigStuntz it is bigger imho, all you need to do is get to 100% - the percentage thing is just a hint

Comment: when I go there now, I see "759 question votes (100% done). 
Your voting ratio is 0.14 - you need to vote on more questions" Is that what you expect? Because I'm at 100% and don't have/deserve the Electorate badge.

Comment: That is a bug then, it should not be showing you 100% done ... fixing today

Comment: damn MATHS !!!!

Comment: sorry, I got the maths right, but the formatting maths were wrong ... it will show 49% done next time we deploy

Comment: how do you count [waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/keyboard-waffles.jpg)?

Comment: @gnat: One, some, several, many, lots ... what more do you need?