# Electorate progress 104%

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Misleading text/percentage for Electorate badge progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116282/misleading-text-percentage-for-electorate-badge-progress)

On my badge progress https://stackoverflow.com/review/ I see this:

[image: It says I'm 104% done?]

It says I'm 104% done? I don't get it? Do I have the badge, don't I? What's going on?

[My badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20654/oscarryz?tab=badges)

Comment: even though this is a dupe, not following why people are downvoting it ... weird

Comment: @waffles Not reading the text below shows a clear lack of research effort.

Comment: @john Have the text been: *.. is 0.24, you need 0.25* I wouldn't have this question in first place. I'm ok with the dv, I've got the answer

Comment: @OscarReyes It says *is 0.24 - you need to vote on more questions*.  I'd say that's fairly explicit.  Or you could, ya know, actually look up [the badge's requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate).

Comment: @John ¬¬ ... or simply post a question on meta .. ok ok, you get me, I'm lazy ( that's why I use StackOverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16353/stack-overflow-for-the-lazy-newbie-developer) :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've only cast 24% of your votes on questions, the badge only awards at 25%. You're almost there, but the percentage thing is a [known issue that they've never taken action on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116282/badge-progress-for-electorate-misleading-text).

As the text below the progress states: `you need to vote on more questions`.